# Need help Chart.js in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

A few days can make a graph, we need your guidance.

Arrow displays the objects, but on the chart nothing is displayed. The search was not successful.

My models:

```
public class Voting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Voice { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateVote { get; set; }
    public string IpAdress { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetVotings()
    {
        List<Voting> votings = db.Votings.ToList();


        return Json(votings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Probably the main problem in the script calling the data did. While it is possible the controller is not properly configured to output data, will be very glad of your help.

My View:

```
 <canvas id="ChartVote" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Chart/GetVotings',
            }).done(function (votings) {
                console.log(votings);
                $.each(votings, function (index, data) {
                    myChart.labels.push(data.Name);
                    myChart.datasets[0].data.push(data.Voice);
                });
            });
        });
        var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartVote");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [],
                    backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has few problems ! First of all, inside your `$.each` you are trying to access `labels` property of `myChart`. But you did not define what `myChart` variable is. So you are going to get an undefined error!

Another thing to think about is, your ajax call is asynchronous. It may take a long time to get the data. So whenever you get the data, you need to execute the code to render the chart with that data. I suggest you move that code to a  method and call that method in your ajax call's success/done event.

This should work.

```
function renderChart(labels, voice) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartVote");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes', data: voice,
                backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {   beginAtZero: true  }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now in your ajax call's done event, you can pass the label array and data array to your RenderChart method.

```
$(function(){

       $.ajax({
               type: "GET",                  
               url: '@Url.Action("GetVotings","Chart")',
              }).done(function (votings) {
                var labelsArray = [];
                var dataArray = [];
                  $.each(votings, function (index, data) {
                      labelsArray.push(data.Name);
                      dataArray.push(data.Voice);
                  });
                  renderChart(labelsArray, dataArray);
       });

});
```

Comment: Very grateful for the help and not tell me where you can read about filtering and output the outcome of the result?
Here is the data that I have now. It is necessary that the name was unique, and the Voice summarized. За

Id: 30 Name: Summer Voice: 1
Id: 31 Name: Winter Voice: 1
Id: 32 Name: Spring Voice: 1
Id: 33 Name: Winter Voice: 1
Id: 34 Name: Winter Voice: 1
Id: 35 Name: Summer Voice: 1
 
Where can I read about this and how best to implement controls or in javascript ?